# Displacement root mean square for diffusion and random walks

Tags: diffusion, stochastic-processes

For 1D random walks we have $$x_{rms}=\sqrt{\frac{l^{2}}{\tau } t}\tag{23}$$  (in [this](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/schwartz/files/2-diffusion_0.pdf) lecture) as well as for 2D case we have $$r_{rms}=\sqrt{\frac{l^{2}}{\tau } t}\tag{19}$$, where $l$ is length of a step, $\tau$ is time duration of a step. I've done this random walks simulation with Python and got this result.

However, I can't figure out how the equality of there RMS for 1D and 2D correlates with that fact that from diffusion equation one can deduce that $r_{rms}=\sqrt{2nDt}$, where $n$ is the number of dimensions, $D$ is diffusion coefficient (e.g. http://rpdata.caltech.edu/courses/aph162/2006/Protocols/diffusion.pdf).
So, it seems that from the diffusion equation it follows that  $r_{rms}$ depends on the number of dimensions, but from eq. (19) - not.

I would be grateful if someone clarifies this!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your dynamics with a given step $\ell$ does not
fix the diffusion constant in different dimensions to be the same.
So your diffusion constant in the 2d case is half the diffusion
constant in the 1d case.

You can see this from the diffusion equation solution for a point
source in $n$ dimensions
\begin{equation}
\rho(\vec r,t) = \frac{1}{(4\pi D t)^{n/2}} e^{-\frac{r^2}{4Dt}} \,.
\end{equation}
This is a product of 1-d gaussians in each direction which have
a variance $2Dt$. However, your 2-d distribution's $\sigma_x^2$ is
not equal to your 1-d distribution's $\sigma_x^2$. They are
\begin{equation}
\sigma_x^2 = \ell^2
\end{equation}
for your 1-d case, and
\begin{equation}
\sigma_x^2 = \sigma_y^2 = \frac{\ell^2}{2}
\end{equation}
for the 2-d case. Therefore your diffusion constants are not equal;
your 2-d diffusion constant being half your 1-d diffusion constant compensates
for the $n$ factor in your diffusion constant expression for the $r_{rms}$.